# Azure BitBucket distribution failure

Tags: node.js, git, azure, bitbucket

I got a Visual Studio MSDN subscription on Microsoft Azure Platform so I decided to move my Heroku Applications to the Azure cloud.
I got 3 applications written in NodeJS and 1 application in PHP. I deployed correctly 2/3 nodeJS applications but I can't get what is wrong with the third one. Each app is deployed in a different BitBucket git repository. Repositories for NodeJS have the same configurations:

- - Access level = This is a private repository
- - Forking = Allow only private forks
- - Landing page = Overview
- - Website Language = Node.js

From Azure point of view (using the new Portal) I have this NodeJS app called **rankk** . The Service Plan I am using is a D1. I can correctly see 3 "app and slots". I set the continuous integration pointing to my bitBucket repository for the *rankk* (the application name) application code. The fact is that distribution always fails (see the picture below):
[image: the situation]

I destroyed the Azure web app and created a new one -same situation.
I destroyed the BitBucket git repository, created a new one, created a new web app on Azure and link them - same situation
As far as I understood there some issues with the "distribution" of the application code, but the azure app and the git repository I think they are seeing each other.

If I click the detail of the failure (see picture on the top, red flag) I just see this stuff (see the picture below):
[image: the error details...?!]

I am not getting this: why do I have 4 green flag on the right and 1 red flag on the left?

Last information of the question: the application and the web server logs are both empty. I think this means no distribution success > no party (= no app start).

**--UPDATE**
Thanks to Xiaomin Wu (here below) I reached the last useful log file. See here below:

```
 <step title="Incoming Request" date="2016-01-04T21:30:24.268" instance="fa3789" url="/deploy?scmType=BitbucketGit" method="POST" type="request" pid="3700,2,61" Connection="Keep-Alive" Content-Length="74" Expect="100-continue" Host="rankk.scm.azurewebsites.net" User-Agent="Azure-WebSites-Controller/50.0.8598.1705" x-ms-request-id="b6d3869b-b6e1-44a7-b288-3640647d4283" X-SITE-DEPLOYMENT-ID="rankk" >
    <step title="FetchHandler" date="2016-01-04T21:30:24.268" >
        <step title="Attempting to fetch target branch master" date="2016-01-04T21:30:24.287" />
        <!-- duration: 12ms -->
        <step title="Assuming git repository at D:\home\site\repository" date="2016-01-04T21:30:24.332" />
        <!-- duration: 0ms -->
        <step title="Performing fetch based deployment" date="2016-01-04T21:30:24.441" >
            <step title="Creating temporary deployment" date="2016-01-04T21:30:24.441" />
            <!-- duration: 31ms -->
            <step title="LibGit2SharpRepository Fetch" date="2016-01-04T21:30:24.693" />
            <!-- duration: 0ms -->
            <step title="Warning" date="2016-01-04T21:30:24.693" type="warning" text="LibGit2SharpRepository fallback to git.exe due to Unsupported URL protocol" />
            <!-- duration: 16ms -->
            <step title="Executing external process" date="2016-01-04T21:30:24.708" type="process" path="git.exe" arguments="remote add -t master external &quot;git@bitbucket.org:sturm20/core.git&quot;" >
                <step title="Process dump" date="2016-01-04T21:30:24.740" exitCode="128" type="processOutput" />
                <!-- duration: 16ms -->
            </step>
            <!-- duration: 47ms -->
            <step title="Executing external process" date="2016-01-04T21:30:24.756" type="process" path="git.exe" arguments="remote rm external" />
            <!-- duration: 143ms -->
            <step title="Executing external process" date="2016-01-04T21:30:24.915" type="process" path="git.exe" arguments="remote add -t master external &quot;git@bitbucket.org:sturm20/core.git&quot;" />
            <!-- duration: 641ms -->
            <step title="Executing external process" date="2016-01-04T21:30:25.555" type="process" path="git.exe" arguments="branch" />
            <!-- duration: 47ms -->
            <step title="Executing external process" date="2016-01-04T21:30:25.602" type="process" path="git.exe" arguments="fetch external --progress" />
            <!-- duration: 4937ms -->
            <step title="Executing external process" date="2016-01-04T21:30:30.553" type="process" path="git.exe" arguments="update-ref refs/heads/master external/master" />
            <!-- duration: 109ms -->
            <step title="Executing external process" date="2016-01-04T21:30:30.678" type="process" path="git.exe" arguments="checkout master --force" />
            <!-- duration: 1554ms -->
            <step title="Executing external process" date="2016-01-04T21:30:32.231" type="process" path="git.exe" arguments="remote rm external" />
            <!-- duration: 94ms -->
            <step title="DeploymentManager.Deploy(id)" date="2016-01-04T21:30:32.341" >
                <step title="Collecting changeset information" date="2016-01-04T21:30:32.356" />
                <!-- duration: 31ms -->
                <step title="Updating submodules" date="2016-01-04T21:30:32.403" />
                <!-- duration: 47ms -->
                <step title="Determining deployment builder" date="2016-01-04T21:30:32.513" >
                    <step title="Builder is NodeSiteBuilder" date="2016-01-04T21:30:34.617" />
                    <!-- duration: 0ms -->
                </step>
                <!-- duration: 2104ms -->
                <step title="Copying SSH keys" date="2016-01-04T21:30:34.648" />
                <!-- duration: 17ms -->
                <step title="Building" date="2016-01-04T21:30:34.665" >
                    <step title="Generating deployment script" date="2016-01-04T21:30:34.713" >
                        <step title="Using cached version of the deployment script for command: -y --no-dot-deployment -r &quot;D:\home\site\repository&quot; -o &quot;D:\home\site\deployments\tools&quot; --node --sitePath &quot;D:\home\site\repository&quot;" date="2016-01-04T21:30:34.744" />
                        <!-- duration: 0ms -->
                    </step>
                    <!-- duration: 32ms -->
                    <step title="Executing external process" date="2016-01-04T21:30:35.304" type="process" path="starter.cmd" arguments="&quot;D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd&quot;" >
                        <step title="Process dump" date="2016-01-04T21:31:05.444" exitCode="255" type="processOutput" />
                        <!-- duration: 16ms -->
                    </step>
                    <!-- duration: 30156ms -->
                    <step title="Error occurred" date="2016-01-04T21:31:05.459" type="error" text="npm WARN package.json core@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json core@0.0.1 license should be a valid SPDX license expression
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: 404 status code downloading 32-bit node.lib
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.&lt;anonymous&gt; (c:\Program Files (x86)\npm\2.11.2\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\install.js:377:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.emit (events.js:169:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.onRequestResponse (c:\Program Files (x86)\npm\2.11.2\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:1142:10)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:169:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (_http_client.js:415:21)
gyp ERR! stack     at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:88:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:305:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
gyp ERR! command &quot;D:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\4.2.3\\node.exe&quot; &quot;c:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\2.11.2\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js&quot; &quot;rebuild&quot;
gyp ERR! cwd D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\node-expat
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok 

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! argv &quot;D:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\0.12.6\\node.exe&quot; &quot;D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\2.11.2\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js&quot; &quot;install&quot; &quot;--production&quot;
npm ERR! node v0.12.6
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! node-expat@2.3.9 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-expat@2.3.9 install script &apos;node-gyp rebuild&apos;.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-expat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-expat
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\home\site\wwwroot\npm-debug.log
C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\50.41223.1987\bin\scripts\starter.cmd &quot;D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd&quot;" stackTrace="   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.Executable.ExecuteInternal(ITracer tracer, Func`2 onWriteOutput, Func`2 onWriteError, Encoding encoding, String arguments, Object[] args)
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.Executable.ExecuteWithProgressWriter(ILogger logger, ITracer tracer, String arguments, Object[] args)
   at Kudu.Core.Deployment.Generator.ExternalCommandBuilder.RunCommand(DeploymentContext context, String command)" />
                    <!-- duration: 16ms -->
                </step>
                <!-- duration: 30952ms -->
                <step title="Error occurred" date="2016-01-04T21:31:05.617" type="error" text="npm WARN package.json core@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json core@0.0.1 license should be a valid SPDX license expression
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: 404 status code downloading 32-bit node.lib
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.&lt;anonymous&gt; (c:\Program Files (x86)\npm\2.11.2\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\install.js:377:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.emit (events.js:169:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.onRequestResponse (c:\Program Files (x86)\npm\2.11.2\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:1142:10)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:169:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (_http_client.js:415:21)
gyp ERR! stack     at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:88:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:305:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
gyp ERR! command &quot;D:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\4.2.3\\node.exe&quot; &quot;c:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\2.11.2\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js&quot; &quot;rebuild&quot;
gyp ERR! cwd D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\node-expat
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok 

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! argv &quot;D:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\0.12.6\\node.exe&quot; &quot;D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\2.11.2\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js&quot; &quot;install&quot; &quot;--production&quot;
npm ERR! node v0.12.6
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! node-expat@2.3.9 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-expat@2.3.9 install script &apos;node-gyp rebuild&apos;.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-expat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-expat
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\home\site\wwwroot\npm-debug.log
C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\50.41223.1987\bin\scripts\starter.cmd &quot;D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd&quot;" stackTrace="   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.Executable.ExecuteInternal(ITracer tracer, Func`2 onWriteOutput, Func`2 onWriteError, Encoding encoding, String arguments, Object[] args)
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.Executable.ExecuteWithProgressWriter(ILogger logger, ITracer tracer, String arguments, Object[] args)
   at Kudu.Core.Deployment.Generator.ExternalCommandBuilder.RunCommand(DeploymentContext context, String command)
   at Kudu.Core.Deployment.Generator.GeneratorSiteBuilder.Build(DeploymentContext context)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Kudu.Core.Deployment.DeploymentManager.&lt;Build&gt;d__29.MoveNext()" />
                <!-- duration: 0ms -->
            </step>
            <!-- duration: 33292ms -->
            <step title="Cleaning up temp files" date="2016-01-04T21:31:05.633" />
            <!-- duration: 16ms -->
            <step title="WebHooksManager.PublishEventAsync: PostDeployment" date="2016-01-04T21:31:05.664" />
            <!-- duration: 16ms -->
        </step>
        <!-- duration: 41254ms -->
    </step>`enter code here`
    <!-- duration: 41443ms -->
    <step title="Outgoing response" date="2016-01-04T21:31:05.711" type="response" statusCode="200" statusText="OK" Server="Microsoft-IIS/8.0" Cache-Control="private" X-AspNet-Version="4.0.30319" />
    <!-- duration: 0ms -->
</step>
<!-- duration: 41459ms -->
```

Now: why node-gyp fails to build on the cloud despite builds successfully on my machine? I should ask to the owner of node-expat but he seems to be unreachable (see screenshot below):
[image: node-expat owner]

**--UPDATE 2nd**
As the answer here below suggests, the node version running on my Azure Application was 0.6.x. On my package.json there was the 0.12.6. The 0.12.6 is available on *D:\Program Files (x86)\node > ls* and I set it on the application variable. The problem is solved but changed. Now I got:

```
<step title="Error occurred" date="2016-01-09T23:39:01.588" type="error" text="npm WARN package.json core@0.0.1 No description
npm WARN package.json core@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json core@0.0.1 No README data
npm WARN package.json core@0.0.1 No license field.
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (c:\Program Files (x86)\npm\2.11.2\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
gyp ERR! command &quot;node&quot; &quot;c:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\2.11.2\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js&quot; &quot;rebuild&quot;
gyp ERR! cwd D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\node-expat
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.6
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok 

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! argv &quot;D:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\0.12.6\\node.exe&quot; &quot;D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\2.11.2\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js&quot; &quot;install&quot; &quot;--production&quot;
npm ERR! node v0.12.6
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! node-expat@2.3.12 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-expat@2.3.12 install script &apos;node-gyp rebuild&apos;.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-expat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-expat
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\home\site\wwwroot\npm-debug.log
C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\51.50108.2013\bin\scripts\starter.cmd &quot;D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd&quot;" stackTrace="   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.Executable.ExecuteInternal(ITracer tracer, Func`2 onWriteOutput, Func`2 onWriteError, Encoding encoding, String arguments, Object[] args)
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.Executable.ExecuteWithProgressWriter(ILogger logger, ITracer tracer, String arguments, Object[] args)
   at Kudu.Core.Deployment.Generator.ExternalCommandBuilder.RunCommand(DeploymentContext context, String command, String message)" />
                    <!-- duration: 0ms -->
                </step>
                <!-- duration: 19761ms -->
                <step title="Error occurred" date="2016-01-09T23:39:01.681" type="error" text="npm WARN package.json core@0.0.1 No description
npm WARN package.json core@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json core@0.0.1 No README data
npm WARN package.json core@0.0.1 No license field.
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (c:\Program Files (x86)\npm\2.11.2\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
gyp ERR! command &quot;node&quot; &quot;c:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\2.11.2\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js&quot; &quot;rebuild&quot;
gyp ERR! cwd D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\node-expat
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.6
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok 

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! argv &quot;D:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\0.12.6\\node.exe&quot; &quot;D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\2.11.2\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js&quot; &quot;install&quot; &quot;--production&quot;
npm ERR! node v0.12.6
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! node-expat@2.3.12 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-expat@2.3.12 install script &apos;node-gyp rebuild&apos;.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-expat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-expat
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\home\site\wwwroot\npm-debug.log
C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\51.50108.2013\bin\scripts\starter.cmd &quot;D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd&quot;" stackTrace="   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.Executable.ExecuteInternal(ITracer tracer, Func`2 onWriteOutput, Func`2 onWriteError, Encoding encoding, String arguments, Object[] args)
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.Executable.ExecuteWithProgressWriter(ILogger logger, ITracer tracer, String arguments, Object[] args)
   at Kudu.Core.Deployment.Generator.ExternalCommandBuilder.RunCommand(DeploymentContext context, String command, String message)
   at Kudu.Core.Deployment.Generator.GeneratorSiteBuilder.Build(DeploymentContext context)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Kudu.Core.Deployment.DeploymentManager.&lt;Build&gt;d__29.MoveNext()" />
                <!-- duration: 0ms -->
            </step>
```

Comment: try go to your scm site `https://{your site name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`, and navigate to `D:\home\LogFiles\kudu\trace`. Look for log that contains "POST_deploy". Check to see if there is any error/exception

Comment: question has been integrated with the `DebugConsole\LogFiles\kudu\trace\2016-01-04T21-30-24_fa3789_243_POST_deploy_200_41s.xml` file

Comment: is the app runs fine locally? what version of node and npm do you use locally?

Comment: The app runs fine locally. 
**C:\Users\Francesco >** npm version
{ npm: '2.11.2',
  http_parser: '2.3',
  modules: '14',
  node: '0.12.6',
  openssl: '1.0.1o',
  uv: '1.6.1',
  v8: '3.28.71.19',
  zlib: '1.2.8' }
-- And this is my package.json _{
  "name": "core",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines":{"node": "0.12.6 || 0.8.x"},
  "author": "francesco bacchelli",
  "license": "BSD"
}_

Comment: check my answer below. i think root cause is node version miss-match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the root cause is Azure App Service environment has a higher version of node while Francesco has a very old version of node.

Go to `https://{your site name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` and navigate to `D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs` see all the available nodejs. And check the default nodejs version by `npm version` or `node -v`

To select a specific nodejs version, define a environment variable via application settings

Navigate to your site --> All Settings --> Application settings --> App Settings

Key: WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION, value: {version}

[image]

Comment: the problem is solved but changed. See 2nd question update please. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Francesco saw your updated issue. is that all the error log? can you paste the full log? seems like one of the native module failed to build.

Comment: I provided more log on the 2nd update question section. Also, I `npm install` -ed the _node-expat_ and the _node-gyp_ modules on the node_modules folder of my application but nothing changed.

Comment: found this from github https://github.com/node-xmpp/node-expat/issues/57#issuecomment-21547903, can you give it a try to see if it solve your issue? (Azure App Service x64 enviroment)

Comment: should I run it from the Kudu Remote Console? If so, on the Kudu Remote Console, the "C:\Program Files..." is not a valid directory. I found D:\Program Files\ directory but the folder Microsoft SDKs\ does not exist. In that folder, subfolders are many: now I paste the once maybe interesting: \MSBuild,  \Microsoft Message Analyzer, \Microsoft SQL Server, \Microsoft Security Client, \Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0.   Actually, I don't even know if my app is running on a x64 or a x86 system. Executed the comand: _D:\Program Files>dir /S /P "*Setenv.cmd"_ with **File Not Found** result.

Comment: @Francesco you might want to create an issue on node-xmpp/node-expat, since from log, issue is not able to build "node-expat". the one i found seems back from 2012, might be out-dated.

Comment: seems like there is already an issue "Error installing node-expat" https://github.com/node-xmpp/node-expat/issues/134

Comment: After a code review I chose not to use the npm modules that needed node-expat.

Comment: so i guess not using node-expat solve your second issue then?

Comment: yes. uninstalling every npm modules with dependencies on node-expat solved. I am sorry but I couldn't go any further with the investigation or fix. Already spent too much time on it.

Answer (score 0):

@Francesco, I had the same issue for setting up the continuous integration with BitBucket on Azure new portal. But I found I can do it successfully at the right sidebar of `DASHBOARD` tab page of Azure WebApps on Azure old portal.

So I suggest that you can try to do `set up deployment from source control` with BitBucket on Azure old portal again, please see below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I did that but I still see the red flag (this time the '!' character inside a red triangle). Maybe I should now focus on the node-gyp issue (see updated part of the question).

Comment: @Francesco "Azure Websites does not support all native modules and might fail at compiling those with very specific prerequisites." It's quoted from the section `Native Modules` of the doc https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/nodejs-use-node-modules-azure-apps/, and the native modules need to be compiled by node-gyp within installation, but the doc proved two workarounds that you can try..